# making a list from nlp object is not working while the spacy lecture goes with that approach

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to follow along the lecture from spacy.io.

However, I ran into a strange problem.

Firstly, I share the link for the code from official spacy webpage.

https://course.spacy.io/en/chapter3

in the example code they provide,

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Span

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
animals = ["Golden Retriever", "cat", "turtle", "Rattus norvegicus"]
animal_patterns = list(nlp.pipe(animals))
print("animal_patterns:", animal_patterns)
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("ANIMAL", None, *animal_patterns)
```

When I run this on my jupyter,

The error message was like below.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 5 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
> 6 animals = ["Golden Retriever", "cat", "turtle", "Rattus norvegicus"]
> ----> 7 animal_patterns = list(nlp.pipe(animals))
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

For me it seems like
since nlp is not iterable object, it's not possible to create a list from that.

How do I fix this? and Why do they show this as an example even if it's not working code at all?
is this code based on python 2.x maybe?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your `list` constructor seems to be gone.
This could have been because of operations like `list = something`
Anyways, this should fix it.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Span

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
animals = ["Golden Retriever", "cat", "turtle", "Rattus norvegicus"]
list = [].__class__
animal_patterns = list(nlp.pipe(animals))
print("animal_patterns:", animal_patterns)
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("ANIMAL", None, *animal_patterns)
```